# como imprimir numero grande en tabla con tabulate python

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un programa con diversas tablas, el problema es que en una tabla tengo una variable tipo int que tiene 1008000 como valor pero me lo imprime como un elevado y lo que quiero es que se muestre el numero entero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿como lo podria solucionar?

Comment: Para empezar, muestranos como imprimes el número.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede desactivar la notación científica en tabulate con   `disable_numparse=True`.

Por defecto, la notación está activada:

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [["Sun",696000,1989100000],["Earth",6371,5973.6],
         ["Moon",1737,73.5],["Mars",3390,641.85]]
print(tabulate(table))
```

```
-----  ------  -------------
Sun    696000     1.9891e+09
Earth    6371  5973.6
Moon     1737    73.5
Mars     3390   641.85
-----  ------  -------------
```

Pero se puede desactivar:

```py
print(tabulate(table, disable_numparse=True))
```

```
-----  ------  ----------
Sun    696000  1989100000
Earth  6371    5973.6
Moon   1737    73.5
Mars   3390    641.85
-----  ------  ----------
```